# React problema con setState

Tags: reactjs

soy nuevo en React y tengo el siguiente codigo hecho. El problema que estoy teniendo es que cuando llamo al "this.validName(this.name)"  al metodo de validName le llega undefined "this.name". Como deberia acceder al name para poder validarlo dentro del metodo de validName()?

```
class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isEmailValid: false,
            isNameValid: false,
            isPhoneValid: false,
            isUrlValid: false,
            name: '',
            phone: '',
            email: '',
            url: ''
        };

    };

    verify = () => {
        this.setState({
            isEmailValid: this.validEmail(this.email),
            isNameValid: this.validName(this.name),
            isPhoneValid: this.validPhone(this.phone),
            isUrlValid: this.validUrl(this.url),
        })  
    };

    validName = (value) => {
        if (value.length < 3 || value.length > 30) {
            return /^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(value);
        }

    }

render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
            <h1 className="text-center">Form Validation</h1>
            <form>
                <h3>Name: 
                </h3> 
                <input type="text" >{ this.name }</input>
            </form>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varios problemas:

- Estás llamando a `this.name`, cuando debería ser `this.state.name`
- Desconozco desde donde llamas a la función `verify`, pero también es incorrecto lo que haces en cada una de las llamadas a funciones `this.valid...`, donde deberías anteponer `this.state` en cada uno de los nombres de estado.
- Cuando declaras un input, más importante a que muestres su valor por pantalla es que setees su valor. En otras palabras `<input type="text" value={this.state.name} >`.

Creo que sería bueno que revisaras [la documentación de react](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs) respecto a manejo de formularios. Saludos

Comment: A tener en cuenta, igual no es la pregunta pero por adicionar algo, debería crear un `onChange` para setear los datos de vuelta al estado cuando cambia el input, de otra forma no podría escribir en el input

Comment: @GermanAlzate si, totalmente, de hecho es por lo cual le linkeé la doc de react, porque veo que hay problemas de fondo que no se resolverán solo con mis sugerencias. Pensándolo nuevamente, creo que debería haber solo comentado el link, pero en fin...:P

Comment: Si, ya pude encontrar el error, ambas cosas estaba haciendo mal, no usar el this.state.name y despues cambiarlo con un metodo en el onChange, muchas gracias a ambos.